# search line by line in file in c

Tags: c, file

I want to search line after line in c, I am using this code

```
user = fopen("user.txt","r");
rewind(user);
while(fgets(string_handler,250,user) != NULL)
{
    sscanf(string_handler,"%s %s %c",e.user_e,e.pass_e,&e.account_e);
    if(strcmp(user_name,e.user_e) == 0)
    {
        printf("\n\tUsername Already Exits choose another one!");
        break;
    }
    if(e.account_e == account_type)
    {
        printf("\n\tYou already have this kind of account!");
        break;
    }
    fclose(user);
}
```

So what I want to do is that I want to search record from this file. But this code only searches for the first record. I have 3 record lines in the file and it only searches the first one.

Comment: You're closing the file at the end of the loop.  `fgets` is thus failing.

Comment: i don't think you need to rewind a freshly opened FILE pointer if you open with "r"

Comment: It doesn't work even if I dnt close the file at the end! I am just opening the same file with "a". If the record doesn't match!

Answer (score 4):

1. Put `fclose(user)` after the `while(fgets())` loop.
2. Remove `break;` when the record is found.